# Object of type 'AuthToken' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm getting the above error when creating token, here's the code:

```
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from rest_framework.response import Response 
from knox.models import AuthToken
from .serializers import UserSerializer, RegisterSerializer

class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    user = serializer.save()
    return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)
    })
```

what am I doing wrong here

Comment: Well you will need to serialize the `AuthToken` as well, like you did with the user (or pass an attribute of that token that can be converted to JSON (like a `str`, `int`, etc.). An `AuthToken` itself is, at least not without some extra logic, serializable).

Comment: How to serialize AuthToken ?

Comment: With a serializer, just like you did with the `UserSerializer`.

Comment: ok, got it, it's a tuple which can't be serialized, doing this worked AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1].

Comment: This seems to be a change in `django-rest-knox`.  I have a project with `django-rest-know v 3.6.0` using the code you have in the post.  I'm just starting an new project (using version 4.0.1), and I've had to add the `[1]` to the token serialization.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The Token.objects.create returns a tuple (instance, token). So in order to get token use the index 1

`"token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]`

Comment: But is that the real token which we need to work with. What i mean is when we print AuthToken.objects.create(user) it gives output like this;   (<AuthToken: long_token : username>, 'another_token')   and when i checked the database, the "long_token" is stored in the database not the "another_token"  but the method you are using returns "another_token".

Answer (score 15):

Better way is use this method in python

```
_, token = AuthToken.objects.create(user)
return Response({
    "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
    "token": token
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular error occurs because the Token.objects.create returns a tuple (instance, token). just use the second position [1] by using instead of former

```
"token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Django rest framework auth token do this:

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

...
# The token will be in token variable, created variable will be a bool
token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

# Object of type Token is not JSON serializable, so convert token to string
token = str(token)
```